# How to I change a form's data in ASP.NET/C# code behind on onclick?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, submit

I have this input in a form:

```
 <input name="keywords" type="text" id="keywordSearch" value="Enter keywords / publication number" class="watermark" />
```

I then have an click function that gets called when the user submits the form.  How do I get the value of the keywords and change it in the click submit function in my code behind?

Is it Form.keywords.value = 'my keywords';?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Request.Form["keywords"]` to retrieve the value that was posted.

Comment: thx i just figured that out, i thought it was read only but guess not (like QueryString)